# Angular's Controller doesn't read service value?

Tags: angularjs

I already have  a code with 2 separate controllers .

Each controller's scope/view has  an `input text` and a `span`.

[image]

All fine.

But Looking at the line with  yellow color label(empty at the moment) - which is found within the *second controller*  , I want the value to be the same value from as in  *first* controller .

so I'm expecting the line to be (and changed automatically) :

> *Value from the FirstController is :First Cntrl*

I already know that I need a serivce :

so here is my code :

```
angular.module('app', [])
       .controller("FirstCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice', function($rootScope, $scope, myservice)
    {
     myservice.messageFromCntrl1= this.message;
        this.message = "First Cntrl";
    }]).controller("SecondCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice', function($rootScope, $scope, myservice)
    {

      this.message = "Second Cntrl";
      this.messageFromCntrl1 = myservice.messageFromCntrl1;
    }])
    .service('myservice', function()
    {
         this.messageFromCntrl1 =  "???";
    });
```

In the first controller I do set

```
 myservice.messageFromCntrl1= this.message;
```

And in the second controller I do read :

```
this.messageFromCntrl1 = myservice.messageFromCntrl1;
```

And in the HTML :

```
   Value from the FirstController is :<span style='color:red;'>{{myservice.messageFromCntrl1}}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I missing?

[**JSBIN**](https://jsbin.com/putegu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: in ctrl 2 you pass the message by value not reference, that's why it's not updating

Comment: I've made 2 plunks before with ways of binding thinks, I hope it will be usefull for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/pt2xwlYqvY3r840tHJ92?p=preview and http://plnkr.co/edit/YOzP2VCPOXwh4qoQC73i?p=preview

Comment: can't access service directly in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your JSBIN, check it [here](https://jsbin.com/tirivuciso/1/edit?html,js,output). I believe it behaves now as you want it to.

```
angular.module('app', [])
   .controller("FirstCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice', function($rootScope, $scope, myservice)
{
   this.message = myservice.messageFromCntrl1;
   this.message.data = "First Cntrl";
}]).controller("SecondCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice', function($rootScope, $scope, myservice)
{

  this.message = "Second Cntrl";
  this.messageFromCntrl1 = myservice.messageFromCntrl1;
}])
.service('myservice', function()
{
     this.messageFromCntrl1 =  {data:""};
});
```

And in your view

```
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl as first">
  <input type="text" ng-model="first.message.data">
  <h1>{{first.message.data}}</h1>
</div>

<div ng-controller="SecondCtrl as second">
  <input type="text" ng-model="second.message"> 
  <h1>{{second.message}} </h1>
  Value from the FirstController is: 
  <span style='color:red;'>{{second.messageFromCntrl1.data}}</span>
</div>
```

First of all, if you want to keep this value updated between controllers you need to use objects and not simple variables. With objects you operate on references and updates are shared between all references of object.

Second, you tried to access service directly in view. You need to bind service reference to controller's scope.

Comment: Code added. Happy that I could help.

Comment: Was chosen due to extra explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I've made an edit to your jsbin, tell me if that's what you need

https://jsbin.com/mapuwojocu/1/edit?html,js,output

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller("FirstCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, myservice) {
      this.message = "First Cntrl";
      this.myservice = myservice;
    }
  ]).controller("SecondCtrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myservice',
    function ($rootScope, $scope, myservice) {
      this.message = "Second Cntrl";
      this.myservice = myservice;
    }
  ])
  .service('myservice', function () {
    return {
      message: 'Cntrl'
    };
  });
```

Comment: That's just a view, check again here pls https://jsbin.com/simiqopunu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score -2):

You can't access service through the view. In addition change all your this to $scope in your controller. 
Look at this example:

```
angular.module('app1', [])
.controller("FirstCtrl", ['$scope', 'myservice', function($scope, myservice)
    {
        $scope.message = "First Cntrl from code";
        myservice.messageFromCntrl1= $scope.message;

    }])
.controller("SecondCtrl", ['$scope', 'myservice', function($scope, myservice)
    {

      $scope.message = "Second Cntrl Code";
      $scope.messageFromCntrl1 = myservice.messageFromCntrl1;
    }])
.service('myservice', function()
    {
         this.messageFromCntrl1 =  "???";
    });
```

Comment: as you can see he is using syntax of 'Controller as', he doesn't have to change to scope to make it work

Comment: Why are you changing to `$scope`? Can't arbitrarily do that if don't change view also. It won't work in view since `controllerAs` is being used